# How to generates an OAuth 2.0 access token for a service account for my firebase project using projects.serviceAccounts.generateAccessToken

Tags: .net, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on FCM(Firebase cloud messaging) to send push notification for users. I am using .NET core to implement that. I am allowing users to create firebase project dynamically, and what i want to do is, to implement push notification integration to all users , which might have different firebase project. In order to implement that i am using FCM topic concept. In order to subscribe a user to this FCM topic, I need to authenticate the method (SubscribeToTopicAsync) using the firebase's project service account json key file, but since i am creating the projects dynamically, i  do not have access to their service account json key file.

In order to by pass that, I am trying to use  the following Api ->

```
https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/{name=projects/*/serviceAccounts/*}:generateAccessToken. I am trying to test this api,
```

and one of the requirement is , to give 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' role to my service account email.

I tried to give that role on the specified project, but still I am getting ->

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can u please give me some idea on this?